# Specific file size on jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, multifile-uploader

I'm using jQuery File Upload UI : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

I'm trying to set a max upload file size depending on the file extension. 
If the file is a video, set maxFileSize: 250Mb
else set maxFileSize: 100Mb.

It's easy to set a general maxfilesize, but is it possible to make it more granular ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this in add

```
var uploadFile = data.files[0];
    if (!(/\.(mp4)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
        if (uploadFile.size > 50000000) { // 2mb
            // Do something here
        }
    } else if (!(/\.(flv)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
        if (uploadFile.size > 50000000) { // 2mb
            // Do something here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i found example like this. But will it work with jquery UI ?